# React useState Hook issue with controlled input component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state, use-state

I've had a controlled class component within my app that I want to turn into a functional component that utilizes hooks. Before, the code worked fine by setting the `event.target.value` within the input and setting the state of `searchTerm` to be that current value. However, since refactoring with hooks, I've noticed an issue with the `searchTerm` state value being the letter before each `event.target.value`. For example, if I type "Joker" in the input bar, using `setSearchTerm(e.target.value)` I would get the searchTerm state as being "Joke" and not "Joker" until I cause another event by hitting a key. I'm not sure why this is happening because when I did this with a class component, setting `this.state.searchTerm` to `e.target.value` would achieve the desired goal. Before if I typed "Joker" into the input field, the `searchTerm` state would actually be "Joker". Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import './SearchBar.styles.scss';
import FontAwesome from 'react-fontawesome';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {searchMovies} from '../../redux/redux-home/home.actions';

const SearchBar = ({ searchMovies }) => {
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
    // constructor(){
    //     super();
    //     this.state={
    //         searchTerm: ''
    //     }
    // }

    const timeOut = useRef(null);

    const doSearch = e => {
        clearTimeout(timeOut.current);
        setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
        // this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});

        timeOut.current = setTimeout(() => {
            searchMovies(searchTerm);
        }, 500);
    }
    return(
        <div className="searchbar">
            <div className="searchbar-content">
                <FontAwesome className="fa-search" name="search" size="2x"/>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Movie" autoComplete="off" onChange={doSearch} value={searchTerm}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    searchMovies: search => dispatch(searchMovies(search))
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBar);
```

`Console.log(e.target.value);` before and after the `setSearchTerm` line both return the correct value; however, `console.log(searchTerm);` before and after the `setSearchTerm` line both return the incorrect value that is one event trigger behind.

Comment: try `searchMovies(e.target.value)`

Comment: That gives an error of undefined - Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: console the event and see what you get

Comment: I get the correct value if I log it. Joker in the input field is Joker in the e.target.value. I'm not sure what's causing setSearchTerm(e.target.value); to be the value but one event trigger behind.

Comment: In my code, I put two console.logs to see the value before setSearchTerm and after. both logs return the value one event trigger behind.

Comment: I've edited the question at the bottom to explain what I'm seeing from these logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `useEffect` to monitor a change of `searchTerm`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // This will be called after searchTerm has been updated
    if (!searchTerm) return;
    clearTimeout(timeOut.current);
    timeOut.current = setTimeout(() => {
        searchMovies(searchTerm);
    }, 500);
}, [searchTerm]);

const doSearch = e => {
    // Just update the state, and let useEffect handle it
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
}
```

Comment: Just one thing, don't forget that useEffect will be called once after mounting, so make sure there is something in searchTerm (I have updated my answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  const timeOut = useRef(null);

  const change = (e) => {
    clearTimeout(timeOut.current);
    setValue(e.currentTarget.value)
    timeOut.current = setTimeout(() => {
      //see the diffetrence here
       console.log('hello', value, e.currentTarget.value)
  }, 500);
    console.log(e.target.value)
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input onChange={change} value={value} />
    </div>
  );
}

import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import './SearchBar.styles.scss';
import FontAwesome from 'react-fontawesome';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {searchMovies} from '../../redux/redux-home/home.actions';

const SearchBar = ({ searchMovies }) => {
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
    // constructor(){
    //     super();
    //     this.state={
    //         searchTerm: ''
    //     }
    // }

    const timeOut = useRef(null);

    const doSearch = e => {
        clearTimeout(timeOut.current);
        setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
        // this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});

        timeOut.current = setTimeout(() => {
         // -----------------------------------
         console.log(searchTerm, e.currentTarget.value)
            searchMovies(searchTerm);
        }, 500);
    }
    return(
        <div className="searchbar">
            <div className="searchbar-content">
                <FontAwesome className="fa-search" name="search" size="2x"/>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Movie" autoComplete="off" onChange={doSearch} value={searchTerm}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    searchMovies: search => dispatch(searchMovies(search))
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBar);
```